# I'm running into this issue when trying to grunt serve. Could anyone help me solve this issue

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

```
roys-mbp:gucci Filthy$ grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Warning: Running "sass:server" (sass) task
Warning: /Users/Filthy/Documents/gucci/app/styles/main.scss:4: error: file to import not found or unreadable: '../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss'
 Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-05-07 07:06:54 UTC)
loading tasks  3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 27%
sass:server    7ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 64%
Total 11ms Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: ...and what did you try in response to the error message that printed?  is the file there?  is it readable?

Answer (score 2):

Try running 'bower install' to install your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the path to bootstrap.scss was wrong.
Did you use the webapp generator?
Change the line 4 in main.scss from
'../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss'
to
'../bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss'
or to whatever the path to the bootstrap.scss may be.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was thinking `npm` and `bower` dependencies was installed, but the installation didn't end.

To fix it:

`npm install
bower install`

That fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your sass file, use this source

@import "bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";

Answer (score 0):

Open cmd promt
go to the project folder
type -> bower install and enter
it will install bower components
and show option to which version need to be installed
then the problem solved

Its working fine for me try it.....